# c++ Cannot create magnifier window

Tags: c++, childwindow, createwindow

Im trying to make a magnification program, but I cannot create the child window without the error 1407, The child window also makes the host windows gui disappear.

```
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED, wc.lpszClassName, skCrypt(_T("magnifier")), WS_POPUP | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, rect.left, rect.top, widthh, heightt, nullptr, nullptr, NULL, nullptr);
    
RegisterClassEx(&wc2);
    magHwnd = CreateWindow(WC_MAGNIFIER, "a", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 250, 250, 250, 250, hwnd, NULL, wc2.hInstance, NULL);
    if (!magHwnd) {
        MessageBox(NULL, std::to_string(GetLastError()).c_str(), "Window Creation", MB_OK);
    }
```

EDIT: the second CreateWindow function works until i add the WC_MAGNIFIER flag

Comment: 1407 means the window class was not registered: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1300-1699-

Comment: @user253751 what class am i registering? wc and wc2 are registered

Comment: The first parameter to `CreateWindow` is not a flag, it's a string with the class name.  Class names must be registered before you can use them.

Comment: The window class you told it to create a window from, which is whatever WC_MAGNIFIER is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to the people that helped me fix this.
I fixed this by changing the classname in wc2 to "Magnifier"